# Get paperclip attachment url from association object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, paperclip, attachment

I have a rails application, which has two table an "Venue" Table & a "Event" Table.

Venue has_many :events, 
Event has_one :venue.

In order to reduce load on the client side, I am selecting only the required columns to be sent using my JSON API.

```
@events = Event.joins(:venues).select("events.name", "events.description","events.image" ,"events.image_file_name" "venues.name as venue_name","venue.area as venue_area", venues.image as venue_image","venues.image_file_name as venues_image_file_name")
```

When I select the image_file_name from the events table I see the correct url of the event image. But in the same process, in the association venue table returns a "null" value.

How do I manage to get the image url from the association table, using SQL queries?

Answer (score 0):

paperclip uses multiple fields for each attachment, in your case these will be `image_file_name`, `image_content_type`, `image_file_size` and so on, see your schema.

Also these fields should be on the model itself. You can try adding `has_attached_file :venue_image` that will read selected venue attributes on the `Event` model. But you'll have to override `url` and `path` parameters because classname, that occurs in path, will be different.

Other straightforward way is to manually generate the url based on filename like paperclip does that.

But in general - paperclip lacks flexibility (and is deprecated), so you should look into other attachment libraries like shrine